# type of reference-captured object inside lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, decltype

The following code works with [gcc](http://rextester.com/JCZJ90740)

```
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::map<int, double> dict;
    const auto lambda = [&]()
    {
        decltype(dict)::value_type bar;
    };
}
```

But for [msvc](http://rextester.com/XOGC56856) I have to additionally use `std::remove_reference`

```
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    std::map<int, double> dict;
    const auto lambda = [&]()
    {
        std::remove_reference_t<decltype(dict)>::value_type bar;
    };
}
```

Otherwise I get [an error](http://rextester.com/ANYWQ21302):

```
error C2651: 'std::map<int,double,std::less<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>> &': left of '::' must be a class, struct or union
```

Which compiler shows the correct behaviour according to the standard?

**update:**

For [msvc](http://rextester.com/WODOOZ34953) `decltype(dict)` really is a reference, as the following code

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, double> dict;
    const auto lambda = [&]()
    {
        decltype(dict) foo;
    };
}
```

errors with

```
error C2530: 'foo': references must be initialized
```

If this really is wrong behaviour, it could lead to [nasty bugs, like dangling references](http://rextester.com/UVJOVR83617) when code is compiled with msvc.

```
#include <map>

std::map<int, double> return_a_map()
{
    std::map<int, double> result;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::map<int, double> dict;
    const auto lambda = [&]()
    {
        decltype(dict) foo = return_a_map();
        // foo is a dangling reference in msvc
    };
}
```

Comment: GCC is definitely right. The only `dict` in sight is the variable in `main()`, and it is not a reference.

Comment: @Quentin the `dict` in the lambda body should be the reference member of the lambda since it is captured by `[&]`.

Answer (score 12):

There is no special rule regarding non parenthesized applications of `decltype` (ie. [[expr.prim.lambda]/20](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#20) does not apply). So we just fall back to the usual definition of `decltype`, which mandates that if the operand is an *id-expression*, the yielded type is just the declared type of the entity, and that's not a reference type. Hence VC++ is wrong.

NB: it doesn't matter whether `dict` is captured or not, because [¶17](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#17):

> Every *id-expression* within the *compound-statement* of a *lambda-expression* **that is an odr-use (3.2)** of an entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the
>   closure type. [ *Note*: **An *id-expression* that is not an odr-use refers to the original entity**, never to a member of
>   the closure type. Furthermore, such an *id-expression* does not cause the implicit capture of the entity. *— end
>   note* ]

`decltype` never odr-uses any of its operands or suboperands. This rule actually gets pretty problematic at times, e.g. as shown in [core issue 958](http://wg21.link/cwg958):

> ```
> int f (int&);
> void* f (const int&);
>
> int main()
> {
>    int i;
>    [=] ()-> decltype(f(i)) { return f(i); };
> }
> ```

Here, `decltype(f(i))` uses the non-`const` `i` from the enclosing scope. However, since the lambda isn't `mutable`, the `i` in the body is actually `const`, hence the trailing-return-type is incorrect. CWG concluded this arises too infrequently to be worth solving.

Comment: Cool, thank you. :) Should we file a bug report or something?

Comment: Hm, so you cannot write something like `[j=i]() -> decltype(f(j)) { return f(j); }`

Comment: @Barry Do you really need the trailing return type?

Comment: @Columbo What if `f(j)` returned a reference? This is just a simplified example - what if the lambda also took an argument and I wanted the sfinae, etc.

Comment: @Barry Well, for the reference case, you can use `decltype(auto)`. SFINAE would be hard to get right elegantly.

Comment: @Barry The code you showed cannot work anyway, because the declarative region of `j` is in the body of the lambda.

Comment: "So we just fall back to the usual definition of decltype, which mandates that if the operand is an *id-expression*, the yielded type is just the declared type of the entity, and that's not a reference type". However, the standard says it's unspecified whether a data member is generated for variables captured by reference, and if it is, then I'd expect that to be the entity (as if the capture were `[&dict = dict]`). Or is that an improper expectation?

Comment: @AndyProwl But I just explained that it is completely irrelevant if it's captured or not. Identifiers in unevaluated operands simply name the original entity.

Comment: @Columbo: Hm, all right, actually I had problem understanding what the "entity" was here (whether the possibly-generated data member or the original captured variable) and where it is specified that it's the original captured variables. OTOH captured variables may only generate *unammed* members in the closure type, so a name of a captured variable can only refer to the original one. Good.

Comment: "the i in the body is actually const", I found it differently on gcc. It was of type 'int' and not 'const int'. AFAIK, Lambda is non mutable, means operator() generated via it is 'const', not  the data members it had via capture.